# Align two div in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Hi I tried to align two div (sidebar and ricetta) in HTML and CSS, but they are positioned one below the other. I want to put ricetta in left and sidebar in right.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Yrsa", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Julius Sans One", sans-serif;
  color: #ae0f26;
  background-color: #fff4f4;
  font-size: 30px;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "Julius Sans One", sans-serif;
  color: #ae0f26;
  background-color: #fff4f4;
  font-size: 20px;
}

a:link {
  color: #ae0f26
}

a:visited {
  color: #e57e92
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none
}


/* valori: circle, disc, square, none */

#head {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 100px
}

#logo {
  width: 357px;
  height: 357px
}

#box-logo {
  width: 400px;
}

#box-menu {
  width: 800px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  float: center;
}

#tabella {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#videoteca {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 12px
}

#video-1 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: left;
}

#video-2 {
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.box #ricetta {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-right: 350px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

#sidebar {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 700px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  width: 250px;
}

#footer {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 960px;
}

#social {
  margin-right: 70px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

#foto-profilo {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
}

.lista li {
  display: block;
}

.contenuto-drop {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff4f4;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(119, 20, 33, 0.3)
}

.dropdown:hover .contenuto-drop {
  display: block;
  border-top: 2px solid #ae0f26;
}

.submenu li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul,
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

hr {
  color: #ae0f26;
}

thead {
  font-family: "Julius Sans One", sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff4f4;
  ;
}


/* Per mettere il testo in maiuscolo :
    tbody {text-transform: uppercase;
           font-size:14px} */

table {
  border: 1px solid #ae0f26;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th,
tr {
  border: 1px dashed #e0919c;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  width: 89px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.light-pink {
  background-color: #fff4f4;
}

.centrato {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.red-text {
  color: #ae0f26
}

.dim-tab {
  width: 100%;
}

#copy {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.white {
  background-color: #ffff
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- validare caratteri inusuali -->
  <title> Titolo </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <!-- collegamento al foglio di stile .css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One|Yrsa:400,500">
  <!-- link relativo ai font scelti -->
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-xymdQtn1n3lH2wcu0qhcdaOpQwyoarkgLVxC/wZ5q7h9gHtxICrpcaSUfygqZGOe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--icone fontawesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
</head>



<body>

  <header id="head">

    <center>
      <div id="box-logo">
        <img src="link img" id="logo" alt=""></img>
      </div>
    </center>


    <div id="box-menu">
      <nav>
        <ul class="red-text">
          <li><a href="index.html" target="_blank">HOME</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="2.html" target="_blank"> 2</a>
            <ul class="contenuto-drop submenu">
              <li><a href="" target="_blank"> 1 </a></li>
              <li><a href="" target="_blank"> 2 </a></li>
              <li><a href="" target="_blank"> 3 </a></li>
              <li><a href="" target="_blank"> 4 </a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">TITLE 2 </a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>







  <div id="table">

    <center>
      <h3>
        <font color="ae0f26">TEST</font>
      </h3>
    </center>

    <center>
      <table>

        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>7</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table>
    </center>
  </div>
  </section>

  <section id="videoteca">

    <div id="video-1">
      <br>
      <center><iframe width="350" height="196" src="" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>
    </div>

    <div id="video-2">
      <br>
      <center><iframe width="350" height="196" src="" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>
    </div>

  </section>
  <hr>
  <!-- hr riga orizzontale -->






  <div class="box">



    <div id="ricetta">

      <center>
        <h1>NEWS 1</h1>
      </center>

      <p align="center">
        TEXT NEWS



        <br><br> test la <span style="color:b62d40">test</span> test
      </p>
      <center><img width="600" src="" </img></center>
      <center>
        <h3>text 3</h3>

        <p>
          <br>text
          <br><br>2
          <br><br>3
          <br><br>4
          <br><br>5
        </p>
      </center>

      <center>
        <h3 id="ancora">text</h3>
      </center>

      <p>
        text text text text

        <br><br>text text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text text

        <br><br>text text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text text

        <br><br>text text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text text

        <br><br>text text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text text

        <br><br>text text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text text
      </p>

      <br>
      <center><img width="600" src="" </img></center>

    </div>


    <div id="sidebar">

      <table class="dim-tab white">
        <tr>
          <td>

            <h3>text</h3>
            <center><img src="" id="foto-profilo"></img>
            </center>
            <p>text text</p>

            <h3>text</h3>
            <p><a href="text"><i class="far fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> <br> text</a></p>

            <h3>text</h3>
            <ul id="social">
              <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-f" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Facebook</a></li>
              <br><br>
              <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Instagram</a></li>
            </ul>

            </p>


      </table>
    </div>

  </div>
  <br><br>


  <div id="footer">
    <br><br>
    <footer class="light-pink centrato">&copy copyright 2018</footer>
    <p class="centrato red-text" id="copy">
      <i>copyright</i>
    </p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Other times I managed to align due to div but this time unfortunately not.
The problem in the css concerns only those two called tags "sidebar" and "ricetta".

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish? It would be incredibly helpful if you could provide a link to what we should see... e.g. [example](https://codepen.io/bradevans/pen/dKeaVb?editors=1100). Are you trying to position that red bordered box toward the bottom and at right more toward the top and left?

Comment: Check out css floats: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: I would not use floats as they're not meant for layout. Most likely a simple css [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) is the solution you're looking for.

Comment: I would like to align the vertical bar below (where there are social networks) next to NEWS 1

Comment: center and font tags are obsolete and should not be used and images don't need a closing tag - they are self closing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you actually need to do, is to do:

```
.box { display: flex }
```

and remove the rules u have made for `#ricetta` and `#sidebar`.

I fixed most of your html syntax errors. You can see a working example here:

```css
body {
        font-family: "Yrsa", sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

.box {
 display: flex
 }
    h1 {
        font-family: "Julius Sans One", sans-serif;
        color: #ae0f26;
        background-color: #fff4f4;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    h3 {
        font-family: "Julius Sans One", sans-serif;
        color: #ae0f26;
        background-color: #fff4f4;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    a:link {
        color: #ae0f26
    }

    a:visited {
        color: #e57e92
    }

    a:link {
        text-decoration: none
    }

    /* valori: circle, disc, square, none */

    #head {
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 100px
    }

    #logo {
        width: 357px;
        height: 357px
    }

    #box-logo {
        width: 400px;
    }

    #box-menu {
        width: 800px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        float: center;
    }

    #tabella {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-right: 100px;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    #videoteca {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-bottom: 12px
    }

    #video-1 {
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        float: left;
    }

    #video-2 {
        margin-right: 100px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        float: left;
    }

    .box #ricetta {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #sidebar {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #footer {
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 960px;
    }

    #social {
        margin-right: 70px;
        margin-left: 25px;
    }

    #foto-profilo {
        width: 60%;
        height: 60%;
    }

    .lista li {
        display: block;
    }

    .contenuto-drop {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #fff4f4;
        min-width: 150px;
        padding: 12px 15px;
        z-index: 1;
        margin: 0;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(119, 20, 33, 0.3)
    }

    .dropdown:hover .contenuto-drop {
        display: block;
        border-top: 2px solid #ae0f26;
    }

    .submenu li {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    ul,
    li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }

    hr {
        color: #ae0f26;
    }

    thead {
        font-family: "Julius Sans One", sans-serif;
        background-color: #fff4f4;;
    }

    /* Per mettere il testo in maiuscolo :
        tbody {text-transform: uppercase;
               font-size:14px} */

    table {
        border: 1px solid #ae0f26;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td,
    th,
    tr {
        border: 1px dashed #e0919c;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    th {
        width: 120px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    td {
        text-align: center;
        width: 89px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .light-pink {
        background-color: #fff4f4;
    }

    .centrato {
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .red-text {
        color: #ae0f26
    }

    .dim-tab {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #copy {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .white {
        background-color: #ffff
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="it">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- validare caratteri inusuali -->
    <title> Titolo </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- collegamento al foglio di stile .css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One|Yrsa:400,500">
    <!-- link relativo ai font scelti -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/js/all.js"
            integrity="sha384-xymdQtn1n3lH2wcu0qhcdaOpQwyoarkgLVxC/wZ5q7h9gHtxICrpcaSUfygqZGOe"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--icone fontawesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<header id="head">
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <div id="box-logo">
            <img src="link img" id="logo" alt="logo"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="box-menu">
        <nav>
            <ul class="red-text">
                <li><a href="index.html" target="_blank">HOME</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="2.html" target="_blank"> 2</a>
                    <ul class="contenuto-drop submenu">
                        <li><a href="" target="_blank"> 1 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="" target="_blank"> 2 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="" target="_blank"> 3 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="" target="_blank"> 4 </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">TITLE 2 </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<div id="table">
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <h3>
            <span style="color: #ae0f26">TEST</span>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>2</th>
                <th>3</th>
                <th>4</th>
                <th>5</th>
                <th>6</th>
                <th>7</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>

            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<section id="videoteca">
    <div id="video-1">
        <br>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <iframe width="350" height="196" src="" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="video-2">
        <br>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <iframe width="350" height="196" src="" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<hr>
<!-- hr riga orizzontale -->

<div class="box">
    <div id="ricetta">
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <h1>NEWS 1</h1>
        </div>
        <p align="center">
            TEXT NEWS
            <br><br> test la <span style="color: #b62d40">test</span> test
        </p>
        <div style="text-align: center"><img width="600" src=""/></div>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <h3>text 3</h3>
            <p>
                <br>text
                <br><br>2
                <br><br>3
                <br><br>4
                <br><br>5
            </p>
        </div>

        <div style="text-align: center">
            <h3 id="ancora">text</h3>
        </div>

        <p>
            text text text text
            <br><br>text text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text text
            <br><br>text text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext
            text text texttext text text text
            <br><br>text text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext
            text text texttext text text text
            <br><br>text text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext
            text text text
            <br><br>text text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text texttext text text text
        </p>

        <br>
        <div style="text-align: center"><img width="600" src=""/></div>

    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
        <table class="dim-tab white">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3>text</h3>
                    <div style="text-align: center">
                        <img src="" id="foto-profilo"/>
                    </div>
                    <p>text text</p>
                    <h3>text</h3>
                    <p>
                        <a href="text">
                            <i class="far fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>
                            text
                        </a>
                    </p>

                    <h3>text</h3>
                    <ul id="social">
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-f" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Facebook</a></li>
                        <br><br>
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Instagram</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>

<div id="footer">
    <br><br>
    <footer class="light-pink centrato">&copy copyright 2018</footer>
    <p class="centrato red-text" id="copy">
        <i>copyright</i>
    </p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: CSS grid is the way to go as I've highlighted in my answer. There was another answer here that also proclaimed that flex was the correct way to solve this problem. There was some back and forth on it earlier about the correct usage of flex/grid and it appears the person who posted it has come around since they've deleted they're answer and all related comments. Just because something works doesn't mean it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated pen: https://codepen.io/bradevans/pen/dKeaVb?editors=1100

The only change is to add a wrapper (.container) around your elements and add:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 1fr;
```

But you have a number of things going on here that have been addressed in the comments. `<center>` and `<font>` tags are obsolete. `<img>` tags don't need a closing tag, they are self closing as per Pete's comment.

Spend the time and bring yourself up to speed with modern HTML5 and CSS3. It'll make you a better, faster developer!